# How to communicate to external system using Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm using Azure Function App to get some files from SFTP server. My function is in Consumption plan. Is it possible to communicate to external system in this service plan?

In Isolation plan we can use Vnet to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "external system"?

Comment: external system means AWS and SFTP server.

Comment: Your function can make outbound calls, no matter if in consumption plan or app service plan. Have you actually tried it? This should work just fine

Comment: If you just want to get file from SFTP server, i believe Logic App is more convenient.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sftp

Comment: agreed with @GeorgeChen, logic apps are easier to deal with sftp, they have a connector, also data factory provides a very robust sftp connector, if you are forced to use an azure function, we've had very good luck with renci sftp, aka ssh.net

Comment: I should configure VNet in function app to communicate to on-premise systems.